# jquery - prevent a draggable link from opening when I drop it

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a grid 5 x 5 of droppable squares and then also several draggable squares which are links like . When moving them between the squares on the grid there is no problem but I also have a 'trash' droppable square where if the user drop a draggable on it is delete it.

My grid of squares with an example draggable looks like this -

```
<div id="-2:-2" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="-2:-1" class="droppable occupied">
    <a href="http://stackexchange.com" id ="20" class="bookmark draggable black" title="black" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
<div id="-2:0" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="-2:1" class="droppable"></div>
```

Elsewhere on the page I have the trash can item -

```
<div>Delete me<div id="trash"></div></div>
```

Then I have the javascript -

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ start: function() {$('#dropdownAddTile').slideDown();},  stop: function() {$('#dropdownAddTile').slideUp();}, containment: '#container', snap:'.droppable, #trash', snapMode:'inner', revert:'invalid',snapTolerance: 32});
$('.droppable').droppable({drop: handleDropEvent, accept: function(e){if(e.hasClass('draggable')) { if (!$(this).hasClass('occupied')) {return true; }}}});
$('#trash').droppable({drop: removelink, accept: '.draggable'});
function removelink(event, ui) {
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    $(ui.draggable).remove();   
    $.post("tiles/delete", { draggableId:draggableId }).done(function(data) {
        //alert(data);
    })
    $('#dropdownAddTile').slideUp();
}
```

All the squares, be they .draggable .droppable or #trash are all the same size etc in the css. However, when I drag and drop on the trash can the underlying link will sometimes pop open. This doesn't happen on the other droppables, just the trash can one.

I know about the start and stop functions but I don't think they make a difference to me. Any one any ideas on how to stop the link from firing?

Comment: not sure what the handleDropEvent is however why don't you call the removelink function within that if it's dropped in trash

Comment: I left the handleDropEvent function out just because it's not really part of the code. All that happens in it is it sends some vars off via ajax to update the database.

Comment: but instead of drop: handleDropEvent you could do drop:function () {
handleDropEvent();
removelink($(this).find('a'))
})

and in your removelink function you could have function removelink(object, event, ui) {

}

Comment: I'm pretty certain your `id` attributes are invalid; they can't contain `:` characters (used in CSS for pseudo-selectors and pseudo-elements) and I don't *think* the `-` character is a valid first character (but I'm really not sure; though this is unlikely to have any bearing on your problem).

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. @JamesDaly The removelink function is actually whats meant to be called as the drop: function when I'm hooking up the #trash to be .droppable

Comment: instead of drop:removelink try drop:funciton(event, ui) {
 var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    $(ui.draggable).remove();   
    $.post("tiles/delete", { draggableId:draggableId }).done(function(data) {
        //alert(data);
    })
    $('#dropdownAddTile').slideUp();
}

might make a difference?

Comment: or ui.draggable.find('a').removeAttr('href')
if you have a fiddle or live site it would be much easier to test :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I'm guessing

```
 $('.droppable').droppable({drop: function () {
 handleDropEvent();
 removelink($(this).find('a'))
 }, accept: function(e){if(e.hasClass('draggable')) { if (!$(this).hasClass('occupied'))      {return true; }}}


function removelink(obj) {
 obj.removeAttr('href');
}
```

meaning just call an extra function when it's dropped

Answer (score 2):

it helps for modern browsers:

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```